# Conditional Vertex Selection with radius not working in Meshlab

Tags: mesh, point-clouds, 3d-modelling, meshlab

I'm using meshlab to process a dense point cloud right now. I'm trying to remove some points that have radius bigger than a certain number from the center, but could not get Meshlab to select those points. I'm using Conditional Vertex Selection, but the (rad > 0) function is not selecting any point at all. I also centered the bounding box at the origin.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUPQi.png)

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what the "rad" variable refers to, but I don't think it is a spherical distance from the center. However if you want to select vertices  larger than a spherical radius from the center, you can use something like `(sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2) >= 100)`, replacing `100` with whatever radius you want.

*Shameless plug:* [MLX](https://github.com/3DLIRIOUS/MeshLabXML) incorporates both cylindrical and spherical selection shortcuts as functions mlx.select.cylindrical_vert & mlx.select.spherical_vert.